# How to stop calling next() on a generator before StopIteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have a function that calls an API and yields the data.  Later I use `next()` to retrieve the data from the generator, however since I don't know how much data there is to be "extracted" I end up executing `next()` until it raises the `StopIteration` Exception.

```
def get_data():
    source = API_Instance()
    yield source.get_some_data()

def parse_data():
    data = get_data()
    while True:
        try:
            row_data = next(data)
            print(row_data)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

This seems like an awful way to do it. Is there a way for me to avoid the Try/Except block? Like a way to know that the generator is exhausted? (*couldn't find a better word for it*)

Comment: A `for`-loop will call `next()` for you and `raise StopIteration` as well. Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `StopIteration` exception *is* how the iterator reports that it’s done. There is an easier way to loop over an entire iterator, though:

```py
def parse_data():
    data = get_data()

    for row_data in data:
        print(row_data)
```

Comment: Interesting, I actually tested something similar before posting, but it was printing the reference to the generator object. Now I realized that it was because I was using a `for i in range(x): yield i` to simulate `get_data()`. lol